# How to know if HttpURLConnection actually sent the request out on the underlying socket?

Tags: java, android, networking

AFAIK HttpURLConnection doesn't actually send the request out until we attempt to read the input. However, if an exception happens here I can't differentiate between the case where the request was not sent, and the case where the request was sent but some other sort of error occurred (maybe we entered a tunnel so couldn't receive the response).

Is there a way to query and find out if the request was actually sent or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some luck with

```
URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// write to connection output stream (don't forget to flush())
connection.getResponseCode();
```

You can get a full list of response codes at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Having said that I can imagine your data going out completely an instant before you enter a tunnel and the connection not having a response code set, in which case you would try to send again (perhaps using a unique 'send id') so that the listener knows to ignore you resend but can still let you know that it was received.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately we don't have that sort of mechanism in place so we can't resend actions -- it might lead to duplicate actions taking place. I guess that's what we'd have to do in the end though -- have the listener tell us that the request was received, because otherwise the acknowledgement could always be lost and once the packet has left our device we can't be sure if it was received or not.